# Como evitar inyección sql y ataques xss, crfs en laravel?

Tags: laravel-8, seguridad, inyección-sql

Tengo una duda sobre estas vulnerabilidades, estuve investigando y lo que encontré es que con eloquent de laravel ya tiene incorporado esto. Pero tengo mis ciertas dudas:

1. **Recibiendo** **parámetros** de **formularios**: Hay que agregar algo a la variable para mas seguridad o no hay necesidad?

   ```
    public function show($id){
    $paciente = Paciente::with('ciudad')->with('sede')
        ->with('eps')
        ->with('hijos')
        ->find($id);

    return view('pacientes.show', compact('paciente'));
   ```

   }
2. En los **formularios** con todos los **verbos**: POST,GET,PUT tienen que llevar crsf o menos en el GET?

   ```
    <form method="GET" action="{{ url('reporte/fechas') }}" autocomplete="off">
      <h4 class="text-center">Obtener total seguimientos por rango de fechas:</h4>
          <div class="form-inline d-flex justify-content-center">
             <div class="form-group">
                <label for="nombre">Fecha inicial: </label>
                <input class="form-control " type="date" name="fecha_ini" id="fecha_ini"/>
             </div>
          </div>
    </form>
   ```
3. Utilizando el facades **DB**: hay que agregarle algo mas para la seguridad?

   ```
        public function index(Request $request){
        $texto = trim($request->get('texto'));
        $paciente = Paciente::all();

        $seguimientos = DB::table('seguimientos as s')
            ->join('pacientes as p', 'p.id', '=', 's.paciente_id')
            ->join('users as u', 'u.id', '=', 's.user_id')
            ->where('s.estado', '=', 'A')
            ->where(function ($query) use ($texto) {
                $query->where('p.identificacion', 'LIKE', '%' . $texto . '%')
                    ->orWhere('p.apellidos', 'LIKE', '%' . $texto . '%')
                    ->orWhere('p.nombres', 'LIKE', '%' . $texto . '%')
                    ->orWhere('s.prioridad', 'LIKE', '%' . $texto . '%');
            })
            ->select(DB::raw("CONCAT(u.nombres,' ',u.apellidos)AS psicologo "), 's.id', 'p.identificacion', 'p.nombres', 'p.apellidos', 's.prioridad', 's.abuso_sexual', 's.autoestima', 's.fecha', 's.numero', 's.cedula')
            // ->orderBy('s.updated_at','desc')
            // ->orderBy('s.prioridad','Alta')
            // ->orderByDesc('prioridad')
            ->latest('id')
            ->paginate(10);



        return view('seguimientos.index', compact('seguimientos', 'texto'));
    }
   ```

Se les agradecería que compartieran su experiencia  y sus conocimientos si estoy errado.